# Including a varying labels in user defined function

Tags: r

I need to write an R function where the input is two qualitative variables that outputs a frequency table, chi-squared test, and a bargraph by one of the two variables. I can get the basic bargraph but I need to add titles and a legend that will depend on the name of the variables used. I tried to use the cat and deparse function to substitute in the variable names but the plot is still printing without any title, axis labels, or legend.

```
fx1=function(y,x){
  yy=as.factor(y)
  xx=as.factor(x)
  v=ftable(yy,xx)
  f=chisq.test(y,x)
  g=barplot(v, main= cat("Barplot of ", deparse(substitute(y)), 
                         " by", deparse(substitute(x))), 
            xlab= deparse(substitute(x)), 
            ylab = 'Frequency', names.arg=c(names(x)))
  r=c(v,g,f)
  return(r)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (the only change I made is fixed parenthesis in your function and substitute `cat()` on `paste()`

```
fx1=function(y,x){
  yy=as.factor(y)
  xx=as.factor(x)
  v=ftable(yy,xx)
  f=chisq.test(y,x)
  g=barplot(v, main= paste("Barplot of ", 
                            deparse(substitute(y)), 
                            " by", 
                            deparse(substitute(x))), 
            xlab= deparse(substitute(x)), 
            ylab = 'Frequency', names.arg=c(names(x)))
  r=c(v,g,f)
  return(r)
}

myx <- sample(c("M","F"), 10, replace = TRUE)
myy <- sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = TRUE)
fx1(myx,myy)
```